How to make a bar chart in React Js with custom bar component?
I am trying to create a height comparison chart where I want to display the SVG's of kids, men and women based on height instead of bar. But, sometimes, my SVG does not appear completely on the chart and sometime appear but not as bars equal to bar length. Instead some cut part of the svg on some side of the chart.
I tried using nivo, recharts, react-chartjs-2 but nothing worked for me. The custom bar component is not showing up and there is no proper documentation for them also.

Your question is unclear. In order to help with an answer, you're going to need to be more specific or give a codesandbox/mockup with what you have vs what you want to achieve

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
